# Excel: If cell<>0, then do this formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that does two things:

1. Checks to see if the inputted value is 0
2. If that value is not 0, then checks to see if that inputted value divides cleanly by 13.

Here's what I have, and it is not accepting 0. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

```
=IF(M10<1, 0, if(MOD(M10/13,1)=0,M10,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do what you asked in question first:

```
=IF(M10 = 0,
    do something if it is equal to 0 ,
    IF(MOD(M10, 13) = 0,
    do something if it is divisible by 13
    )
 )
```

`MOD` takes two parameter as input:

1. The number
2. The divisor, in this case 13

Your formula is wrong because you divide `M10` by 13, rather than putting the 13 in the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to simply display the cell value if M10=0, what would that look like?

Comment: Just put `M10` on the first `IF`, or `0`, both shows the cell value, which is `0`

Comment: OK. When I try to use this formula and enter 13 into M10, it throws a "value you entered is not valid error."

`IF(MOD(M10, 13), M10, 0)`

Comment: My bad, see my code fix. It should have `MOD(M10, 13) = 0`